# “Untitled” item on my MacBook Pro desktop

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, finder, macos

I just installed macOS El Capitan, and now I see there is an `Untitled` item on the Desktop:

[image: Untitled]

This item contains the following directories:

[image: Contents]

I’ve never seen anything like this on the `Desktop` before. When I look through the Finder, I don’t see this item.

What's the issue here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just your system hard drive. You didn’t provide a name when you formatted it, and so macOS gave it a default name of `Untitled`.

You can rename it by right-clicking it in the **Finder** sidebar under the heading *Devices*, or by opening **Disk Utility** and right-clicking it there. Then simply choose `Rename`.

You can also hide hard drives from your desktop by going into the menu bar **Finder** → **Preferences** → **General** and *unchecking* `Hard disks` under the heading *Show these items on the desktop*.

Comment: Okay, gone, thanks a lot. Just before you go - is it something normal?

Comment: Yes, that is just standard macOS behavior on fresh installs.

Comment: Yes it is normal and yes it is your internal disk. (just to pile on and strenghten the position)